# How to retrieve specific data contents in database from servlet to jsp using java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am developing one web application and following MVC pattern and using hibernate and postgresql.I have data in my data base tables.Now my servlet retrieves the data from data base by accessing bean classes using select statement and returns as a list.And in my jsp I have drop down list.If I select one option from that then the data related to that option should be displayed on the browser.How can I achieve this.I am new to JSP.Please help me.I know I can display it using ${}.But using which statement I am able to access data of selected option from drop down list.
For Example in my application if I select one option say "XYZ" then I should get only XYZ details from Person table.How to achieve this.

And one more doubt is only specific values like name and roll number only these two values related to XYZ from Person table I should get.

Please clarify these two doubts.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you send the `List` from model to the `JSP` ? Please show us some code which you have written .

Comment: Using RequestDispatcher I am sending the request from servlet to jsp and forwarding the request along with the list of values that I got from the data bases.I am following MVC.

Comment: Then you can use the JSTL to display it , as described in the answer !!

Comment: But how do I send the selected value from jsp to servlet back.My first doubt is that one.I am selecting one option from drop down list.Then I have to inform the servlet that I have choosen this option and based on this selected option get me the data contents from data base related to selected option.How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to make a `request` to the Servlet which can be a conventional request or an AJAX call . There are lots of tutorials to do that .

Comment: Can u please provide me some links.I am new to jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the core taglib - so add this at the top of the JSP page :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Then e.g. (where "users" is for example a List of objects with a public getName() method):

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${users}">
        <li>    
             <c:out value="${user.name}"/>
        </li> 
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you..but how do I send the selected value from jsp to servlet back.My first doubt is that one.I am selecting one option from drop down list.Then I have to inform the servlet that I have choosen this option and based on this selected option get me the related information.How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have two things you need to do here - 1) is to render the information in the browser. 2) Is to send the users selection back to the server for processing.  This has to be done via HTTP - e.g. a form or ajax request, you then need to extract parameters from the the request in the JSP or Servlet that handles it.

Comment: Exactly what I want to do.How can I send selected option value from jsp to servlet.Using request.getParameter("selectedoption") can I achieve?

Comment: You cannot send it "from the JSP to the servlet" it is sent over HTTP from the browser to the servlet container - how to do this is beyond the scope of this question.